# Implementing internet communication for WCF user-applications with use of master server

Tags: .net, wcf

I have two .NET apps, in traditional server-client(s) model, that communicate with each other with WCF-implemented communication (TCP duplex, only ethernet was considered as the communication was implemented).

Now, I need to extend the communication functionality over the internet, with maximum reliability. Simply adding NAT UPnP to server application is out of the question, as it won't work everywhere.

I do have a "master server" which I can use to "bind up" the communication for the applications.

Now, my question is, is there any way to create a service on the master server that would sort of "transport" the communication over the internet ("feed" the server application with client data and vice-versa). To my current knowledge, there is no possibility of such thing, but hey, it is worth asking.

If not, what'd be the best way to re-use current communication (**not** write entire new modules for internet WCF communication, where both apps work in client mode connected to master server)?

My current idea is to have the server application query the master server x times a second, send it the data meant for clients associated with it, and receive data that clients send to the master server. Then each application "emulates" the other client/server locally, using the data from the master server. Though it kinda feels like not the best idea ever..

EDIT: just to clarify, the master server solution does not have to be based on .NET and/or WCF (though, it can be). Anyway, I am looking more for ideas and mechanisms than actual snippets of code.

Comment: Have a look at [WCF Routing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee517423(v=vs.110).aspx) for protocol translation

Comment: WCF Routing looks promising, but in my case the services are user-apps that will be dynamically appearing and disappearing (also, behind all kinds of NAT, physical routers etc.). Is there a way to make the services connect to router, not the other way around?